# How to map a string property to a binary column in the database?

Tags: postgresql, fluent-nhibernate, binary, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have a class for a user entity. One of the properties is the user's password (a hash, actually). I made it a string (streamlined code):

```
public class User
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Password { get; set; }
}
```

There's also a Fluent NHibernate mapping (streamlined code):

```
public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        Table("users");
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Sequence("users_id_seq");
        Map(x => x.Password); // what do I put here???
    }
}
```

The database column is of [bytea](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/datatype-binary.html) data type on PostgreSQL. The above mapping doesn't work, because the property is string (text). What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can Make `Password` a public property, which is only used to reference to the underlying private property `HashedPassword`.
something like so:

`protected virtual byte[] /*or whatever the type is*/ HashedPassword {get; set;}
public virtual string Password

  get

  {

     return (string)(HashedPassword); //or however you want to cast it to string...

  }

  set

  //...`

you can then tell fluent nHib to ignore your Password property.

Comment: I did it a bit differently: http://www.pastie.org/2162631

But it's along the same line. The idea came from [here](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Fluent_mapping_private_properties)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final solution which works both ways (read & write), what I tried earlier didn't work properly. Hope this will help somebody.

```
public class User
{
    private byte[] _password;

    public virtual int Id { get; private set; }

    public virtual string Password
    { 
        get { return System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(_password); }
        set { _password = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(value); }
    }
}

public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        Table("users");
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Sequence("users_id_seq");
        Map(x => x.Password)
            .Access.LowerCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
            .CustomType<byte[]>();
    }
}
```